# Not able to push elements from one array to another array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a line of code which is trying to push elements from one array to another array.

```
var criArray=[];
jQuery('form').find(':input[name=criteria]').toArray().each(
    function(val) {
        criArray.push(jQuery(val).val())
    }
);
```

When I load the page, in browser console, I am getting below error at this line.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

I am clueless of ways to push elements to array as I tried many answers from my google search. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to do this

```
var criArray = jQuery('form').find(':input[name=criteria]').map(function () {
    return jQuery(this).val();
}).get();
```

The problem is [.toArray()](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) returns an array object which does not have the `.each()` method, you could use [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead

Comment: Getting uncaught reference error in at return jQuery(val).val();

Comment: @Sanjay should be `jQuery(this).val();`

Comment: That's perfect Arun..!